# Caddy on LAN only

Tags: subdomain, reverse-proxy, caddy, caddyfile

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy with [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/), I also want to use subdomains to point to my different services, so I bought a domain but the domain can only point to an ip-address, and my routers ip-address is not static so to solve that I registered a subdomain on [Duckdns](https://www.duckdns.org/) and that subdomain is pointing to my routers ip-address all the time, the subdomains on that I payed for have DNS set to point to [Duckdns](https://www.duckdns.org/) and I have opened port 80 & 443 on my router to point to my server machine that is running [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/), the caddyfile simply have the domains I payed for point to localhost services.

It works but only on LAN, outside it does not work

Comment: Hi omar, I think this might be a better question to have on serverfault or superuser.  Your question here is about DNS setup and networking rather than Caddy.  For Caddy queries you can try https://caddy.community also.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your public IP address is **not** the same as `nslookup mydomain.duckdns.org`; the problem is DNS. *check your dynamic DNS
   client's configuration file for inaccuracies. Restart your router and trial that it works as expected*
2. If the IP addresses match, but you cannot make access from outside the network, its a port forwarding issue. *Check port forwarding rules on your router, and opened ports on your server*.

`sudo ufw status verbose` and `sudo ss -ltnp` are helpful server commands.

3. If the IP addresses match, but you cannot make access from inside
   the network, hairpin NAT is the issue. This is a router issue. *Buy
   a more feature complete router from your ISP, or setup a local DNS
   server to resolve this minor annoyance.*

[Using your phone, enable WiFi for 'inside' type testing; disable WiFi for 'outside' type testing].